# How to direct a user to an available websocket server when she logs in to my multi-server Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, websocket

This is more like a design question but I have no idea where to start.

Suppose I have a realtime Node.js app that runs on multiple servers. When a user logs in she doesn't know which server she will be assigned to. She will just login, do something and logout and that's it. A user won't be interacting with other users on a different server, nor will her details be stored on another server.

In the backend I assume the Node.js server will put the user's login details to some queue and then when there is space it will assign this user to an available server (A server that has the lowest ping value or is not full). Because there is a limit number of users on one physical server when the users try to login to a "full" server it will direct her to another available server.

I am using `ws` module of node.js. Is there any service available for this purpose or do I have to build my own? How difficult would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how `websocket` fits into this question. Ignoring it. I guess your actual question is about `load balancing`... Let me try paraphasing it.

**Q:** Does NodeJS has any `load balancing` feature that I can leverage?

Yes and it is called `cluster` in `NodeJS`. Instead of the traditional one node process listening on a single `port`, this module allows you to spawn a group of `node` processes and have them all binded to the same port.

This means is that all the user know is only the service's endpoint. He sends a request to it and 1 of the available server in the group will serve him whenever possible.

Alternatively using `Nginx`, the web server, as your load balancer is also a very popular approach to this problem.

**References:**

Cluster API: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Nginx  as load balancer: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

**P.S**
I guess the key word for googling solutions to your problem is `load balancer`.

Out of the 2 solutions I would recommend going the `Nginx` way as it is a much scalable approach

**Example:**

Your `Node` process could possibly be spread across multiple hosts (horizontal scaling). The former solution is more for vertical scaling, taking advantages of multi-cores machine.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear for me. I have looked into Kubernetes too. I have used Nginx before but I have never tried this feature. Will there be much coding or just configuration for Nginx?

Comment: @newguy no coding involved. Pure configuration on the `nginx` side to tell it how to find your servers.